# How can we type cast IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ClassA>>> objOld into IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ClassB>>> objNew?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have an object `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ClassA>>> objOld;` which i want to cast  into `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ClassB>>> objNew;`.

ClassA and ClassB both have same objects

```
public class ClassA
{ `public string str1 { get; set; }
    public string str2 { get; set; } 
    public int newNum { get; set; } `
}

public class ClassB
{ `public string str1 { get; set; }
    public string str2 { get; set; } 
    public int newNum { get; set; } `
}
```

I tried following but it is generating exception.

```
objNew = objOld.Cast<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ClassB>>>>();
```

Please let me know possible ways to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) method twice for that. First time to map every `KeyValuePair` to new one, second time to map internal `IEnumerable<ClassA>` to `IEnumerable<ClassB>`. 
There is no way to directly cast `ClassA` instance to `ClassB`, because classes are different. So, you should create `ClassB` instance manually based on properties of every `ClassA` instance

```cs
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ClassB>>> objNew = objOld.Select(o =>
    new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ClassB>>(o.Key, o.Value.Select(a => new ClassB
    {
        str1 = a.str1,
        str2 = a.str2,
        newNum = a.newNum
    })));
```

Answer (score 3):

Only because two classes have the same members does not imply any inheritance-relation. Instead of **casting** one to the other you should create new instances of `B` for every `A`.

```
var result = myInput.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => new ClassB { 
        str1 = y.str1, 
        str2 = y.str2, 
        newNum = y.newNum 
    })
);
```

Or if you really want a list of `KeyValuePair`:

```
var result = myInput.Select(x => 
    new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ClassB>>(x.Key, x => x.Select(y => new ClassB { 
        str1 = y.str1, 
        str2 = y.str2, 
        newNum = y.newNum 
    })
));
```